# lsof doesn't return files open by the same user

Tags: vim, open-files, lsof

Consider this simple scenario:

1. I open a text file ~/textfile.txt with `vim` in one terminal (tried with both edit and read-only modes).
2. In a different terminal, I run

`/usr/sbin/lsof ~/textfile.txt`

Get no results

Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you use `vi`/`vim` to edit a file you aren't actually holding `~/<filename>`open you are reading the file into `~/.<filename>.swp` and then holding that temp file open.

If you run `lsof ~/.<filename>.swp` it will show you the information you are looking for.

**NOTE:** If you have multiple people editing the same file you will need to `lsof ~/.<filename>.s*` as each `vi`/`vim` session will create its own swap file but will name it differently